# I can't "Download Xamarin Live Player from the App Store..."

Tags: iphone, xamarin, download

New to Xamarin and trying to open Xamarin Live Player from App store on my iPhone 6.  App store shows "No Results" for "Xamarin Live Player" even though typing "Xam" automatically found the title, but not a single app.  This is the app that scans the QR code on your PC.  Am I doing something wrong or has this been discontinued or baned from App store?  My coworker tried on his brand new iPhone and same results.

Comment: I last time I tried it, it was available in the Thai country store but not the USA store...

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by TestFlight and then install Xamarin Live Player, you need to register to Xamarin Live Player program and redeem code.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has removed Xamarin from TestFlight. There appears to no longer be a way to use Xamarin Live Player with iOS. Apple appears to have cut this program off to prevent Visual Studio users from previewing their apps on iOS devices without owning a Mac harkening back to the days when they almost went completely out of business by not participating in the free market.